# LinkedList.pollLast() throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, linked-list, nullpointerexception, deque

I use Java 6 Collecetions API. I need a collection that should have only N elements. I mean that if I add new element and collection already have N elements than the last element should be removed and new one add in the head of collection. I have following code fragment to do it:

```
class A {

  int N = 100;
  Deque dq = new LinkedList();

  void add(Object o) {
    synchronized (o) { 
      if (dq.size() == N) {
        dq.pollLast();
      }
      dq.add(o);
    }
  }

  Deque getDq() {
    return new LinkedList(dq);
  }
}
```

Object with type A can be accessed many users in the same time to add new element. In practice I got NullPointerException with it:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at java.util.LinkedList.remove(LinkedList.java:790)
   at java.util.LinkedList.removeLast(LinkedList.java:144)
   at java.util.LinkedList.pollLast(LinkedList.java:573)
   at A.add(A.java:9)
```

Deque.pollLast() contract doesn't say anything about NullPointerException:

> Retrieves and removes the last element
>   of this list, or returns null if this
>   list is empty.

Also adding of elements is synchronized.

Does anyone know what is reason of exception could be?

Thanks for any ideas

Comment: You should synchronize on a common object (i.e. the list, `this` or some special lock object), not on the parameter. No idea if this causes your problem, though.

Comment: Is that the code you use? If so, which language do you run? `Dequeu` has no public field `size` that you could access like this.

Comment: @user: that's a method, you access it without the `()`. I'm aware that this is probably a typo, but that means that the code you show us is **not** the code that has the problem. Please produce a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Are **all** accesses to `dq` properly synchronized? If not, then that's probably your root problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the sycronization is done on the wrong object! It should be `dq` but not `o`!

```
... synchronized (dg) { ...
```

Comment: I agree on that. You are not preventing simultenaous access to your Deque by locking the element you are trying to add/remove.

Answer (score 1):

I've run your code adding using the following test

```
    A a = new A();
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {
        a.add(i);
    }
    System.out.println(a.dq);
```

And it all seems to work correctly.  Can you provide more details on the state of the application when you get the NPE?  What is the object you are trying to add?  What is the state of the Dequeue at that time?

Also, you mentioned

> if I add new element and collection
>   already have N elements than the last
>   element should be removed and new one
>   add in the head of collection

Your code doesn't do that.  Right now, it adds to the tail of the collection.  To add it to the head, change

```
dq.add(o)
```

to

```
dq.addFirst(o)
```

Comment: I think that the real problem here is the synchronization, not the algorithm itself. It can be wrong as well though.

Comment: Very true.  I was trying to rule out algorithm issues, and prompt for further information on how dq is being used and what its state is.  Likely dq is being used in some other non-synchronized way via the getDq() accessor (as others have mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

see [this javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) it says

```
 Removes and returns the last element from this list.
```

first it removes object so if it is null then throws  NullPointerException:

so make add(..) method synchronized and check for size before `dq.pollLast();`

Comment: [LinkedList.pollLast()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#pollLast()) doesn't throw exception if code is well synchronized: